# Multiple instances of User Control on a page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a user control which consists of a textbox, a linkbutton and a jquery dialog, so when the user clicks the link button they get the dialog and select a user name in the list. They select the user, the dialog closes and they see the selected user name in the textbox. This is all working fine. The issue I have is when I have multiple instances of the same user control on my page. The dialog appears, but when they select the user regardless of which instance of the user control they have clicked to open the dialog., it always populates the 2nd textbox.

The javascript to set the textbox value is all in the user control. I have googled it everywhere and everybody says break it out into a seperate file, so I tried this

***User Control***

```
function setUserDetails(id, name) {
    setSelectedValue("<%# tbxSelectedUserName.ClientID %>", name);
    setSelectedValue("<%# tbxSelectedUserId.ClientID %>", id);
    closeSelectUserDialog();
}
```

***External Javascript File.js***

```
function setSelectedValue(control, value) {
    $(control).val(value);
}
```

now nothing gets set. The function is called but no value is shown in either textbox.

Any ideas?

Comment: what does the outputted HTML look like?

Comment: the tbxSelectedUserName is on the page twice which is causing the issue:<input name="ctl00$BodyContent$DelegateOrderApprovalEntryControl$SelectDelegatorUser$tbxSelectedUserName" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="BodyContent_DelegateOrderApprovalEntryControl_SelectDelegatorUser_tbxSelectedUserName" class="width80pc" />